# Image insert overlay broken Chrome for Android

Tags: bug

I'm tagging this as a bug report.

In Chrome for Android, the popup box for inserting images is broken. It jumps all over the screen; if you zoom out then you can see it, but as soon as you start typing it jumps put of view again.

Basically, the popup code needs a complete rewrite for mobile browsers.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an ancient version of Chrome, because... reasons.

Anyways, upgrading to the latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the website in desktop mode, right? The default mobile site doesn't have any formatting tools as far as I can see.

Anyway, in desktop mode, the image thinger pops up to the right but I can scroll over to it and use it just fine. I can upload and type URLs in there.

So no repro here, perhaps a screenshot or recorded video might help work out how to reproduce.

Comment: I've now edited to include a screenshot.